# Creating an object of non-public class outside package

Tags: java, package

In one directory, I have defined the following file A.java:

```
package test; 
public class A {}
class B { 
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

From a different directory, if I do the following:

```
import test.B; 
public class X {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        B b = new B(); 
        b.hello(); 
    }
}
```

and compile `javac X.java`, I get the following error:

```
X.java:2: test.B is not public in test; cannot be accessed from outside package
import test.B; 
         ^

X.java:7: test.B is not public in test; cannot be accessed from outside package
  B b  = new B();
  ^

X.java:7: test.B is not public in test; cannot be accessed from outside package
  B b  = new B();
             ^
```

I cannot change the sources in package test. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried? B is a non-static inner class of A, so at the very least, you need an instance of A to create an instance of B. But your B class isn't available outside of the test package, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: indeed, what i was trying was whacky but necessary for something i was experimenting with. the answer with reflection provides me a reasonable solution. thanks!

Comment: Reflection is madness in this case, but okie dokie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection:

```
package test2;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor<?> bConstructor = Class.forName("test.B").getConstructor(/* parameter types */);
        bConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object b = bConstructor.newInstance(/* parameters */);

        java.lang.reflect.Method hello = b.getClass().getMethod("hello");
        hello.setAccessible(true);
        hello.invoke(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Default access modifier* OR *no modifier specified member* is only accessible in `declared package` but not outside the package.So in your case `B` is only accessible inside `package` named `test`. Read more on [`Access Modifiers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

If you cannot change the sources in package test.Than move your code/class to `test` package.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there are [4 different scope accessibilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public        Y        Y       Y          Y
protected     Y        Y       Y          N
no modifier   Y        Y       N          N
private       Y        N       N          N
```

In your case, `B` has *no modifier*, which means it can be seen inside the class and inside the package only. Therefore, if you create class `X` that is an other package, it won't see `B`.

**To acess `B`, you need to define a class that is inside the same package as `B` which in your case is the package `test`.**